# POS Pricing system in Python

Tags: python

I am making a POS system using Python. I got everything working great but now it's time to really get it going. I want to add an option to get price based on pizza and size. I am think it needs to be stored in a dictionary and dictionary of lists. Anyway, now I am at a impass and can't come up with how to unpack the list properly to do this. Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is the link to the code I am running. Just easier. 
https://gist.github.com/spa1mer/5eba249124d1a237d4adb88395659298

Here is the dictionary I came up with:

```
pizza_prices = {'El Jefe' : [{'small' : 12.99}, {'medium' : 13.99}, {'large' 
: 15.99}], 'OMV' : [{'small' : 13.99}, {'medium' : 14.99}, {'large' : 
16.99}], 'Dirty Hipster' : [{'small' : 14.99}, {'medium' : 15.99}, {'large' 
: 17.99}],}
```

In my theories I know it needs to go somewhere in here with the totals.

[image]

Comment: Post a code block, not a screenshot of a code block, nor a link to your code either. SO has formatting for this. (Perhaps see [MCVE]?)

Comment: I would probably just make a "pizza" class, rather than a dictionary of lists. It seems easier to implement, and would help with future problems/readability

Comment: @peri461 there is a link

Comment: I would definitely order pizza from this place, with names like those.

Comment: You keep saying "POS". I am curious which definition you are using.

Comment: @MadPhysicist http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pos&defid=130584

Comment: @MadPhysicist could go either way. Meant to be a Point of Sale...but if the code is crap is could be Piece of ____ lol

Comment: @SamRussoPalmer I fixed my comment to clarify.

Comment: @SamRussoPalmer links to code, or images of code, or even worse - links to images of code - are bad. Post the code in the quesiton itself as *formatted text*. The easiest way is to copy-paste *directly from your editor* to keep the indentation. Then highlight the text in the editing window on StackOveflow, and press ctrl-k, it and will automatically format it for you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I was aware of the possibilities. Just making sure OP was too...

Comment: If small, medium, large always appear in the same order, you don't need a dict. Just a list will do fine. You can always stash a None for missing elements.

Comment: Try this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This data structure could be significantly improved, but let me try to work with what you have.

```
pizza_prices = {
    'El Jefe' : [{'small' : 12.99}, {'medium' : 13.99}, {'large' : 15.99}],
    'OMV' : [{'small' : 13.99}, {'medium' : 14.99}, {'large' : 16.99}],
    'Dirty Hipster' : [{'small' : 14.99}, {'medium' : 15.99}, {'large' : 17.99}]
}

def get_price(name, size):
    sizes = pizza_prices[name]
    size_dict = list(filter(lambda s: size in s, sizes))[0]
    return size_dict[size]
```

This first grabs the list with the name of the pizza. Then it filters down the list to only the dictionary containing your size of pizza, and finally returns its price.

Finally, please notice that your dictionaries can have more than one entry:

```
{'small': 12.99, 'medium': 13.99, 'large': 15.99}
```

This at least turns your method for extraction into:

```
def get_price(name, size):
    return pizza_prices[name][size]
```